# Simple Point Transformation (Graphics2D)

Tags: java, graph, graphics

I have a simple class that represents a graph, and currently it only draws lines. I'm currently intercepting line definitions before drawing, and changing their points, but now I want to add more complex shapes with more than just point definitions. I know about affinetransform, but I'm not exactly sure how to use it. I want a transform equivalent to:

```
    private Point transform(PlasmaPoint2D plasmaPoint2D) {
        double x = plasmaPoint2D.getX();
        double y = plasmaPoint2D.getY();
        Point p = new Point();
        p.setLocation(x * this.gridScale / this.scale + this.gridScale, y * this.gridScale / this.scale + this.gridScale);
        return p;
    }
```

(Where PlasmaPoint2D is my own, immutable, version of point2d). gridScale is an instance variable specifying the number of pixels between each grid line, and scale is the number of units represented by a single grid box.

I'm not sure how to implement this in AffineTransform, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: affinetransform doesn't actually move the points themselves, it tells a graphics object how to draw the points with a rotation.

Comment: Is there any way to set a move points behavior?

Comment: Lines and arcs. I'd be willing to figure out how to just transform those, but I'd rather have a general solution.

Answer (score 0):

When a transform is chosen from the Transform menu, the transform is concatenated onto the AffineTransform at:

```
public void setTrans(int transIndex) {
    // Sets the AffineTransform.
    switch ( transIndex ) {
    case 0 :
        at.setToIdentity();
        at.translate(w/2, h/2);
        break;
    case 1 :
        at.rotate(Math.toRadians(45));
        break;
    case 2 :
        at.scale(0.5, 0.5);
        break;
    case 3 :
        at.shear(0.5, 0.0);
        break;
    }
}
```

Before displaying the shape corresponding to the menu choices, the application first retrieves the current transform from the Graphics2D object:

```
AffineTransform saveXform = g2.getTransform();
```

After retrieving the current transform, another AffineTransform, toCenterAt, is created that causes shapes to be rendered in the center of the panel. The at AffineTransform is concatenated onto toCenterAt:

```
AffineTransform toCenterAt = new AffineTransform();
toCenterAt.concatenate(at);
toCenterAt.translate(-(r.width/2), -(r.height/2));
```

The toCenterAt transform is concatenated onto the Graphics2D transform with the transform method:

```
g2.transform(toCenterAt);
```

After rendering is completed, the original transform is restored using the setTransform method:

```
g2.setTransform(saveXform);
```

Comment: This sounds like a description from some other class, I don't quite understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Say I have a quad curve:

```
QuadCurve2D.Double c2=new QuadCurve2D.Double(p[j][0], p[j][1], 
  p[j+1][0], p[j+1][1], p[j+2][0], p[j+2][1]);
int translatebyx=x * this.gridScale / this.scale + this.gridScale-c2.getX1(),
    translatebyy=y * this.gridScale / this.scale + this.gridScale-c2.getY1(), 
  AffineTransform at=AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(translatebyx, translatebyy);
  Shape s=at.createTransformedShape(c2);
  g2.draw(s);
```

where I want to translate to a given location as you specify

```
x * this.gridScale / this.scale + this.gridScale,
y * this.gridScale / this.scale + this.gridScale
```

If you want to perform rotation you apply the same procedure (using getRotateInstance()) etc.